# Delete message in mail box using OpenPop.NET

Tags: c#, pop3

I am using OpenPop.NET client to get access to my mailbox via Pop3 protocol. All is fine, except one thing: I cannot delete messages. Even [sample](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleDeleteMessage.php) from official site doesn't help.
I've tried it with several mail servers: gmail.com, yandex.ru, rambler.ru situation is the same.

Update - added code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DeleteMessageOnServer("pop.gmail.com", 995, true, USERNAME, PASSWORD, 1);
}

public static void
    DeleteMessageOnServer(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl, string username,
    string password, int messageNumber)
{
    // The client disconnects from the server when being disposed
    using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
    {
        // Connect to the server
        client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

        // Authenticate ourselves towards the server
        client.Authenticate(username, password);

        // Mark the message as deleted
        // Notice that it is only MARKED as deleted
        // POP3 requires you to "commit" the changes
        // which is done by sending a QUIT command to the server
        // You can also reset all marked messages, by sending a RSET command.
        client.DeleteMessage(messageNumber);

        // When a QUIT command is sent to the server, the connection between them are closed.
        // When the client is disposed, the QUIT command will be sent to the server
        // just as if you had called the Disconnect method yourself.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read that deletion occurs when you quit? Did you try?

Comment: Of course. I tried code from sample page. Tried call `client.Disconnect()` by myself - nothing happened.

Comment: Which Message number are you using? I believe pop3 is 1 based not 0 based. This example code is working for me. I'm using it everyday. I think the problem can be wrong message number. Please note message number is session based.

Comment: Could you put whole your code?

Comment: Code looks good, could you check how many messages is on server using `client.GetMessageCount()`

Comment: @Marcin strange thing.. 
After deleting and disconnecting client, message count is decreased by 1, thats right. But in gmail, web UI I still see this 'deleted' message in inbox folder, not in deleted...
Thats for gmail, as for yandex mailserver, after reconnecting I get same messages count number.

Comment: Are you sure it is deleted message? It looks like you deleting some other message. And messages deleted by pop won't go to deleted folder on server. They will just gone. it is how Pop3 protocol is working.

Comment: When I ran program for the first time, I've got 3 as client.GetMessageCount. Then, I called client.Delete and closed it.
Next time I ran program I've got 2 as client.GetMessageCount. And so on.
But in gmail web UI I can still see all 3 messages.

Comment: I have the same problem. Seekeer, did u find a solution?

Comment: The reason for this is that gmail functions differently from a normal pop3 server. If you are looking to properly delete then you are more likely to have success with either imap (no guarantees) or another gmail api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deletion of the emails that are marked through the `.DeleteMessage(messageNumber);` method happens when the `.Disconnect();` method is called.

Comment: Your answer should be marked as correct. After calling .DeleteMessage(idx) or .DeleteAllMessages(), .Disconnect() has to be called to really excute the deletion. For whatever reason...

Comment: I believe the reason is in set the protocol definition, see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1939#page-10

Comment: IMHO GMail won't delete mails using POP3 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed above emails are deleted when the connection is closed, also the message number should start in one and not in zero. In the case of gmail you need to go to "settings->Forwarding POP/IMAP->When message accesed with POP" and select "delete gmail's copy".

You can check it [here](https://forum.rebex.net/889/unable-to-delete-e-mails-from-gmail-using-pop3).